# Is possible to get data from jpa/hibernate withou define entity or model in spring boot?

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is possible to get data from jpa/hibernate withou define entity or model in spring boot? if possible, how to? thank you...

Comment: JPA needs an entity to do the mapping so no. Unless you use plain SQL with DTO's but then why bother using JPA.

Comment: ok thanks, can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible
for serverside and database you first read

> https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

and for restful ,you must use RequestEntity<> to get a field(s) without a model and send or receive data from JSON.

```
// Field class is a response and this is not model class
    public class Field{
      private String name;

      //getter and seter
    }



@PostMapping("/test")
public void getFields(RequestEntity<Map<String,String>> entity){

   Field field = new Field();
   field.setName(entity.getBody().get("name"));
   System.out.println(field);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch the data without having it mapped to an entity by using nativeQuery and a Tuple class.

```
 List<Tuple> resultList = entityManager
           .createNativeQuery("select id as id, street as street, city as city, country as country from address ", Tuple.class
           .getResultList();

 Tuple firstResult = resultList.get(0);
 assertEquals(1L , ((Number) firstResult.get("id")).longValue());
```

For more information you can read Vlad Mihalcea's blog post
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/